# How do I allow buttons in one class to set the visibility of other panels in other classes?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, visibility, jbutton

I'm having a little trouble with my project.

I have one class that is a panel displaying 4 buttons.

I have 4 classes(only one so far) that are panels displaying various components. These panels will occupy one space and only one panel should be visible at a time.

What I want to do is to control the visibility of the panels with their respective button.
For example, when the user clicks on button1, panel1 should appear, and when button2 is pressed, panel2 appears, etc.

This is my first time working with a GUI in java and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

These are the options before you, (Given in the order I guess the most suitable for you)

1. [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)

   > A CardLayout object is a layout manager for a container. It treats each component in the container as a card. Only one card is visible at a time, and the container acts as a stack of cards.

   for more info see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
2. [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html)

   > A component that lets the user switch between a group of components by clicking on a tab with a given title and/or icon

   for more info, see [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)
3. [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)(Maybe an undecorated one)

   for more info see [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 4):

CardLayout is the best option for your requirement.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CardLayoutDemo.htm

Answer (score 1):

As with the other answers, in a recent GUI I created I used CardLayout to accomplish this task.

The solution is simple, have one panel in your Parent JFrame that will hold the CardLayout and when you add each panel you want to show you associate a String with it so you can grab it later such as:

```
panelManager.add(typeSelectionView, TYPEVIEW);
```

Where panelManager is my JPanel containing my layout (Which you have to add before this so you can use this add() method.

Ensure you are storing these Strings which identify your hidden panels in some form, as I have here with my final variables, and when it comes time to show this panel which is hidden within the layout simply call:

```
cl.show(panelManager, newPanel);
```

Where in my case, newPanel was calculated by the controller and handed down to the view. It uses the final Static Strings in the view's Class.

Answer (score 0):

Although `CardLayout` is already suggested, and even a link to the Swing tutorial already provided, I will add some sample code which makes use of the `CardLayout` as an answer.

```
public class CardLayoutDemo {

  private static JFrame createGUI(){

    JFrame testFrame = new JFrame(  );
    testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    List<String> layoutConstraints = Arrays.asList( "first", "second", "third");

    final JPanel contentsPane = new JPanel(  );
    final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout(  );
    contentsPane.setLayout( cardLayout );

    //listener which will be used to switch between the different layouts
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent aActionEvent ) {
        String constraint = aActionEvent.getActionCommand();
        cardLayout.show( contentsPane, constraint );
      }
    };

    //add components to card layout with specific constraint
    for ( String constraints : layoutConstraints ) {
      contentsPane.add( new JLabel( constraints ), constraints );
    }

    //create buttons allowing to switch between the different layouts
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    for ( int i = 0; i < layoutConstraints.size(); i++ ) {
      String constraint = layoutConstraints.get( i );
      JButton button = new JButton( "Layout " + i);
      button.setActionCommand( constraint );
      button.addActionListener( listener );
      buttonPanel.add( button );
    }

    testFrame.add( contentsPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    testFrame.add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    return testFrame;
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = createGUI();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```